# New PC won't POST or boot

Tags: post

I finished the build of my new PC, and when I go to turn it on, nothing happens. I get no video and no POST beep. I removed the ram and turned it on again and it began to beep non stop. I used a voltammeter to check if the APX_12V was putting out 12V and it was on both 4x4 prongs. It also seems like the CPU isn't receiving any power because after letting it run for 20 minutes, the CPU didn't heat up at all.

Comment: There is almost always some kind of indicator that the motherboard is getting power. Usually it's a tiny LED light on the board somewhere, or it's the fan spinning, a short beet [you already said you didn't get that.] etc...Is there no indication whatsoever of the motherboard getting power? If not, and if you're _SURE_ the PSU is 10/10 then you almost certainly have a bad MOBO.

Comment: I didn't say that the mobo isn't getting power, I'm sure it is because the CPU fan and the system fan are spinning. ``

Answer (score 1):

You can't conclude much from the CPU not heating up, as your system isn't running under any load if it doesn't get past POST.

You should try eliminating options in hope of finding your problem:

Start out with unplugging anything that isn't necessary. So leave in:

- PSU (make sure you've properly connected both the 24pin ATX power and the CPU power, 4 or 8pin)
- CPU and CPU-cooler (make sure the CPU fan is connected)
- memory (one stick of RAM is enough for testing)
- if your CPU has built-in graphics, let the system run with that for now

Also, double check any cable connections and make sure the CPU and heatsink are firmly in place.

Now power on with just these components connected and see if you get a POST beep. If not, try replacing with a different stick of RAM to test if the memory is defective.

At this point, you should also try resetting the BIOS. Refer to your motherboard manual for this, but usually it's done by removing the battery from the motherboard and switching a jumper on your motherboard.

If you hear any beep codes at this point, consult your motherboard manual

If you do get POST, you can try connecting more components one-by-one to find the part causing the boot failure:

- more RAM
- SSD
- hard drive
- optical drive (if any)
- graphics card

If you don't get post with minimal setup, then you should start testing PSU, motherboard etc. The best way to do this is with spare parts that are known to be working.

Also see [this guide](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbysymptom/ht/nothingonscreen.htm) which goes through these steps (and others)

Comment: Actually the CPU will heat up noticeably when powered on regardless of load. The fact that the CPU is not heating up *at all* is a good clue.

Comment: Just did everything you said and still nothing. No post beeps or error beeps. I even removed all the components and put them back in making sure that every connection was secure but still nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you've got some defective hardware then. Confirm your PSU is working by testing it in another machine if possible, then start looking for replacement motherboard etc.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to double check that the CPU is compatible with your motherboard, or that the CPU is seated properly.

Comment: So verify there are no bent pins

Comment: It is compatible. FM2 and FM2. This machine was working before and now nothing

Comment: what is your mobo, and CPU?